# How do I check if CGRect intersects with any SpriteNode?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

A little of background: I have function `spawnBubbles()`, which uses output of another function `determineSpawnPoint()`.

`determineSpawnPoint()` returns random `CGPoint`. There is also action, which spawns SpriteNodes once 0.5 second in the random X coordinate `CGPoint`.

The problem: as `determineSpawnPoint()` is random, sometimes 2 or 3 SpriteNodes in a row created nearby, so they intersect with each over.

What do I want to achieve: create a function

```
 func checkForFreeSpace(spawnPoint:CGPoint) -> Bool{
        //some code 
    }
```

which returns `true` if there is free space around certain point.

So, basically, when I get new random `CGPoint`, I want to implement a `CGRect` around it, and check if this rectangle intersects with some `SpriteNodes` (speaking in common sense, if there is free space around it)

Answer (score 3):

You can create two `CGRects` from the point and nodes and use `CGRectIntersectsRect` function to check whether they intersect. The function returns `true` if they intersect.

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(rect1, rect2))
{
    println("They intersect")
}
```